# Overloading standard mathematical functions for custom types

Tags: c++

Suppose I'm writing a class representing a mathematical object for which it makes sense to define various standard operations.

By overloading the arithmetical operators I can enjoy the fact that any templated algorithm using them will work as expected when given my class. But what if the algorithm uses something like *std::pow*?

The standard seems to state that only template specializations of functions in the *std* namespace are allowed, meaning that I am not allowed to write my own overload of *std::pow* for my class. But if that's really the case, what's the best approach to ensure genericity nevertheless?

Comment: get them to use your `pow` via adl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yakk's comment is the right answer. You put your `pow` in your namespace, just like the standard put its `pow` in `std::`. Argument Dependent Lookup means that `pow(x,y)` will look in the namespaces of the types of `x` and `y`.

Experienced library writers know how to use ADL effectively, but TBH I wouldn't immediately know a library that has good reason to call `pow` on objects of unknown type.

Comment: Maybe OP want to implement the automatic differentiation, then `std::pow` of `auto-diff-node` makes sense.